# Is it possible to use @commands.is_owner with @client.group in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have imported `discord.ext` and `discord.ext.commands`
I have defined the `owner_id` attribute when defining my client variable

```py
@client.group(aliases=['owncmds'])
@commands.is_owner()
async def ownercmds(ctx):
    if ctx.invoked_subcommand is None:
        em = discord.Embed(title="Hello, owner.",description="Here are the commands that only you can use!",color=discord.Colour.blue())
        em.add_field(name="b?clearconsole",value="Clears the console.")
        await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

When I run the command, it doesn't give me a response, nor an error.

Comment: Please, share a full code of your command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Yes,

After a bit of testing, it does work, this is the response I got after copying your code and pasting it to a bot: [The working embed from the command that is specified in the question:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GTZf.png)

If this does not work for you, you could just use an if statement to check whether the id is equal to yours (if you are the owner), to add this if statement to the specified command it would be:

```py
@client.group(aliases=['owncmds'])
async def ownercmds(ctx):
    if ctx.author.id = "add your id here without the quotes":
        if ctx.invoked_subcommand is None:
            em = discord.Embed(title="Hello, owner.",description="Here are the commands that only you can use!",color=discord.Colour.blue())
            em.add_field(name="b?clearconsole",value="Clears the console.")
            await ctx.send(embed=em)
```